# Unsupported vendor-prefixed style property webkitAppearance. Did you mean WebkitAppearance?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webkit

Today I started working on a new machine. Yesterday I pushed all changes and everything worked proparly.

I just sat down to keep working on my projecy and all of a sudden im getting tons of errors. I will ignore the rest for now, because I think this one might be causing others to show.

"Unsupported vendor-prefixed style property webkitAppearance. Did you mean WebkitAppearance?"

It's in a several places in my app, just one example:

```
<div className="d-flex flex-column" style={{marginBottom: 0}}>
```

I get that it's something to do with my style. Is there perhaps I am missing something on my new machine? Previously I was on win7 now on fresh win10.

Will be grateful for any help or tips.

Answer (score 3):

In React, all properties of a style object that are vendor-specific must start with a capital letter (except the `ms` prefix). Hence `WebkitAppearance`.

Perhaps your new machine had a different version of React.